# Using an ember-data numeric attribute with `<input type="number">`

Tags: ember.js, casting, ember-data

## Understanding isDirty - A simple situation with unexpected results

Before I get to my question, some context. I have an ember-data project

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember             : 1.11.1
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 1.0.0-beta.16.1
DEBUG: jQuery            : 1.11.2
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 0.7.3
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

#### An Ember-data model

I have a simple model containing some string attributes and some number attributes. This is my `app\models\simplemodel.js`

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  code: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  a_number: DS.attr('number'),
  another_number: DS.attr('number'),
  related_stuff: DS.hasMany('someothermodel', {async: true})
});
```

#### A handlebars template with bound `<input type="number">` elements

I have a template in which I set the number parameters with a bound `<input type="number">` element.

```
<header>
  <h2>{{model.code}}</h2>
  <h2>{{textarea value=model.description placeholder="description"}}</h2>
</header>
<section>
  <p>
      <label>A number:&nbsp;</label>{{input type="number" value=model.a_number}}
      <label>Another number:&nbsp;</label>{{input type="number" value=model.another_number}}
    {{#if model.isDirty}}
      <button {{action 'save'}}>Save</button>
    {{/if}}
  </p>
</section>
```

## The problem/Unexpected behaviour

When I change the value of the `<input type="number">` elements the save button appears as expected. However, when I reset the value back to the original value the save button remains. The model `isDirty` is still true even though the values match the original values.

#### Possible explanation

Now, I understand that the `<input>` element will store its content as a string rather than a number. Presumably, when I change the value of the bound `input` it sets the bound model attribute to its value. It could be that the original value was say `1` but the by using the `<input>` element I am changing the value to `"1"`. However, the model explicitly declares this attribute to be a `DS.attr('number')`. Indeed, when I save the model it dutifully sends a number in the payload to the server.

```
{"simplemodel":{"code":"34735337888888","description":"Some description","a_number":4,"another_number":5}}
```

This is expected, ember-data deals with communication with the server and has cast the `DS.attr('number')` attributes to numbers. So I guess the actual value of the model attribute before it is sent to the server is still a string and hence the model `isDirty`.

A simple test which supports this is that if I change the attribute to `a_number: DS.attr('string')` then **the problem goes away**. With a string attribute the `isDirty` flag flips when I change the input element and flips back when I return the input to the original value. Of course, this will send data to the server as a string.

## The question

The problem seems to be that `isDirty` is being over sensitive when comparing a string from the input element with the original number from the model. Can I somehow set the model attribute to a number even though the input field is providing a string?

#### Possible solutions

I can see two obvious ways to handle this.

1. Make a version of the input element that transparently casts strings to numbers - I have tried this with no luck - probably because I don't understand how ember works.
2. Have the model cast values to the appropriate type automatically.

My instinct would be to go with `1` as `2` feels like it would be more likely to produce unexpected behaviour.

#### My attempt

I tried to produce a component to use for all input elements bound to numbers.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['value', 'type'],
    tagName: 'input',
    type: 'number',
    number: null,

    value: function() {
      var number = this.get('number');
      return number;
    }.property('number'),

    change: function() {
      var value = this.$().val();
      this.set('number', parseFloat(value));
    }
});
```

When I used this, the `isDirty` flag was not set at all even when the value of my component was changed. I don't understand this anyway, it was adapted from something I've been using for date fields. Do I need to do something else here?

Comment: from the docs - "If this property is true the record is in the **dirty state. The record has local changes that have not yet been saved by the adapter.** This includes records that have been created (but not yet saved) or deleted." Changing the values back doesnt mean the record wont be dirty, itll still be dirty because it has been changed. You could do a comparison with the old values and the new dirty values and if they match do a `rollback()` - http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollback - "If the model isDirty this function will discard any unsaved changes"

Comment: @Craicerjack Perhaps. However, I have noticed that when I edit a string attribute such as the `description` attribute in my model the `isDirty` flag switches on and off accordingly.

Comment: You could make Ember.copy of the original model record and compare the Copied object to the current state model values "E.g this.set('copiedObject', Ember.copy(this.get(loadedModel));"

Comment: The problem seems to be that isDirty is being over sensitive when comparing a string from the input with the original number from the model. Can I somehow set the model attribute to a number even though the input field is providing a string?